# Clone UIImageView during UIView addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a menu that requires me to generate dynamically.

```
UIImageView *menu_item = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_item"]];

[menu_item setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 30)];
[menu addSubview:menu_item];

[menu_item setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 10, 30)];
[menu addSubview:menu_item];

[menu_item setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 10, 30)];
[menu addSubview:menu_item];
```

where `menu` is a `UIScrollView`. Only the last `menu_item` is shown.

I know I can re-run `initWithImage` to make all 3 menu items appear, but is there a quicker way to clone the `UIImageView`?

*Note: I know looping. Don't tell me the codes can be simplified via for-loop.*

Comment: When you say "quicker", do you mean from a performance point of view? Can you define "clone"?

Comment: For your case better make a single image contains all the 3 menu items and add that image view in one shot

Comment: Yes, performance wise. Don't want to initalize so many variables with same content. My definition of "clone" in this case is to the item 3 times.

Comment: @Shan thanks for the reply, but this can't work at this case. The real scenario is more complicated, and there are other items in between these identical menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you really don't need to worry about performance.  UIImage imageNamed: has caching built into it to increase performance, and UIViews are very light weight.

If this menu could potentially have hundreds of items in it, then you should be using a UITableView or a UICollectionView instead of a UIScrollView.  Their cell reuse is extremely efficient and easy to implement.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I just feel init an image view multiple times with same content a bit redundant, in terms of coding.

Comment: @Raptor in that case I think that a for-loop is the only way to simplify the code further.

Answer (score 0):

When I am not using a UITableView for navigation, I often use an array of dictionary items.

```
NSArray *navigationItems = @[
    @{@"DashboardViewController": @"Home"},
    @{@"DocumentsViewController": @"Documents"},
    @{@"IncidentViewController": @"Incidents"},
    @{@"HelpViewController": @"Help"},
    @{@"SettingsViewController": @"Settings"}
];
```

Then my layout code can loop through the array:

```
 //Create Naviation Elements
__block int containerViewHeight = 0;
__block NSString *navigationLabel;
__block NSString *navigationClass;
[navigationItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    navigationClass = [[obj allKeys] lastObject];
    navigationLabel = [[obj allValues] lastObject];

    UIButton *navigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    navigationButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [navigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [navigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
    [navigationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadNavigationController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [navigationButton setTitle:[navigationLabel uppercaseString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [navigationButton setTitleColor:[UIColor navigationButtonFGColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [navigationButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Eagle-Bold" size:20]];
    [navigationButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor navigationButtonBGColor]]; //Didn't want to store in memory the original colour. So if you change this, change resetButton aswell.
    navigationButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, ((navigationItemHeight + kNavigationPadding) * idx) + (kNavigationPadding  * (idx + 1)), navigationMaxSize.width, navigationItemHeight);
    navigationButton.tag = idx;
    navigationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
    [navigationButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];

    [navigationView addSubview:navigationButton];

    //Add Height To Container View
    containerViewHeight += navigationItemHeight + (kNavigationPadding * 2);
}];
```

The button action goes into a method called `-(void)loadNavigationController:(id)sender`

- I find out which button you clicked via the senders tag
- I get the class view controller that you wanted to load as its the key of the dictionary
- Then I push that view controller using `[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init]`, (I also have check if the viewController you wish to load is already in the stack and pop instead.)

There is also a check to see if you want to override the default UIViewController alloc init. If the first key in the dictionary is a method name, it fires that instead.

```
//CustomFunction?
SEL customImplementation;
if([self respondsToSelector:(customImplementation = NSSelectorFromString(className))]){
    [self performSelector:customImplementation];     
    return;
}
```

In doing this i have been able to add and remove new navigation items with ease. This solution may not be everybody's cup of tea, and I definitely would recommend a table view.

Hopefully this may give you some ideas to help you in your situation. I have copied the code from a project of mine, apologies if i missed some ivars.

W

Comment: Understand what you are trying to explain, but this doesn't quite relate to my question. My question is about re-using a `UIImageView`.

Comment: There was a thin line. UIImageView doesn't cohere to NSCopy so if you re-use an existing reference it will break things. I certainly found this out the hard way when images started disappearing. You will have to alloc init each time. Sorry.